# Filtering data in mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql code:

```
SELECT
    aza_subjects.subject_name,
    `aza_assessements`.`assessement_name`,
    aza_assesmentxmarks.mark
FROM
    aza_assesmentxmarks
INNER JOIN aza_assessements ON `aza_assessements`.`assessement_id`=`aza_assesmentxmarks`.`assessement_id`
INNER JOIN aza_subjects ON aza_subjects.id=aza_assesmentxmarks.`subject_id`
ORDER BY `aza_assessements`.`assessement_name` ASC
```

It retrieves something like this.

[image: MYSQL RESULT]

How can I filter the data such that I present it in this format

```
**Assessment|** **TEST 1**|**TEST 2** |**AVERAGE**
```

I want the above as headings of the table. The headings have to be dynamic because there are other assessments other than the test 1 and test 1.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
        derived.subject_name,
        derived.assesment_name,
        AVG(mark)          
    FROM
        (SELECT
            aza_subjects.subject_name AS A,
            `aza_assessements`.`assessement_name` AS B,
            aza_assesmentxmarks.mark AS C              
        FROM
            aza_assesmentxmarks              
        INNER JOIN
            aza_assessements                      
                ON `aza_assessements`.`assessement_id`=`aza_assesmentxmarks`.`assessement_id`              
        INNER JOIN
            aza_subjects                      
                ON aza_subjects.id=aza_assesmentxmarks.`subject_id`              
        ORDER BY
            `aza_assessements`.`assessement_name` ASC) derived 
    GROUP BY
        derived.subject_name,
        derived.assesment_name
```

Comment: Thanks @gogibogi, but how do I structure it in a PHP table such that each subject is in one row together with test 1 mark and test 2 mark

Comment: I have edited the answer above. It should work now. I'm sorry I didn't read the question right.

Comment: Thanks. It gives an error that "Unknown column 'derived subject_name in field list "